# threading with idapython

Tags: python, ida

I am writing a plugin for IDA by idapython. When I try to use threading, the IDA program fails.

For example, when I try to run the code:

```
import thread  
def run():  
    print "start thread"  
print "start"  
thread.start_new_thread(run, ())  
print "end"
```

the word "start" is printed in the IDA python console, and then IDA fails.

What can I do?

Comment: As I recall, IDA is singlethreaded and doesn't do any data synchronization - using multiple threads is a fast way to corrupt your data.

Answer (score 3):

Try upgrading your IDA / IDAPython. Using IDA 6.1 and the IDAPython that came with it, the above code works for me.

That said, you really can't access the database from multiple python threads in this version. See [idaapi.execute_sync](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/idaapi-module.html#execute_sync) for more info.